# symfony, cant pass validation on a embedded form + file

Tags: forms, file, validation, symfony

Trying to embed a collection or just a simple type containing a file field, but both result in the same problem. On post the UploadedFile is present, but validation fails. "This value is not valid."

Bashing my head in all day, anyone?

Company form:

Simple embed with a file:

```
$builder->add('logo', new FileType(), [
    'label' => 'Logo',
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => [
        'accept' => 'image/*',
    ]
]);
```

Collection with files:

```
$builder->add('images', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new FileType(),
    'data' => [
        new File(),
        new File(),
        new File(),
    ],
));
```

FileType:

```
class FileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $data = $builder->getData();

        $builder->add('file', 'file', [
            'label' => 'Bestand',
        ]);

        $builder->add('submit', 'submit', [
            'label' => 'Save',
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'file';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\File',
        ));
    }
}
```

The entity has a functioniong one-to-many from Company to File.

Everything works, but when the form is submitted. Both fields have a "This value is not valid." error.

Here is a dump of the clientData preSubmit:

```
 'logo' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[13]
      private 'test' => boolean false
      private 'originalName' => string 'etc.jpg' (length=13)
      private 'mimeType' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      private 'size' => int 103843
      private 'error' => int 0
  'images' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[14]
          private 'test' => boolean false
          private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2014-07-24 at 17.15.30.png' (length=38)
          private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
          private 'size' => int 84102
          private 'error' => int 0
      1 => null
      2 => null
```

Seems perfectly fine to me!